# A Riddle For a Fast Day Away

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> It's a kind of a change. It's a kind of a chance.
>   It's a kind of a run. It's a kind of a dance.
>   It's a kind of escape. It's the start of a game.
>   Yet from middle to end, it stays somehow the same.

The answer is a single English word.

Addendum:
Some post-solution fun.
**May contain spoilers!**

> When it's up then it's sad: to the French *c'est dommage*.
>  When it's down then it's time to go find a garage.
>  When it's through, it's a triumph! The news is a-buzz!
>  When it's in, it's illegal so call for the fuzz.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One suggestion is a

> Break

It's a kind of a change.

> Many types of change can be called a break - say a break in a voice or the weather.

It's a kind of a chance.

> It could be say a lucky break.

It's a kind of a run.

> A team making a break for it in football when running forward. Also a run of scoring in snooker.

It's a kind of a dance.

> A breakdance.

It's a kind of escape.

> A prison break or escape from a situation.

It's the start of a game.

> In snooker/pool, you would break the triangle of balls to begin.

Yet from middle to end, it stays somehow the same.

> Move the middle letter to the end and it still sounds the same (BRAKE)

Title: A Riddle For a Fast Day Away

> May compound break to make - breakfast, daybreak and breakaway

Extra fun - or homework for not getting all the first clues!

> When it's up then it's sad: to the French c'est dommage. - *Breakup*
>  When it's down then it's time to go find a garage. - *Breakdown*
>  When it's through, it's a triumph! The news is a-buzz! - *Breakthrough*
>  When it's in, it's illegal so call for the fuzz. - *Breakin*

Comment: Thanks for this - but afraid I'm stuck on the last line.

Comment: The way to get a fast day to go away is to eat Breakfast.

Comment: Congratulations! BTW, the question now has an addendum that you might want to address just for laughs. (I know. An answerer's work is never done!)

Answer (score 2):

> Ball

It's a kind of a change.

> a whole new ball game

It's a kind of a chance.

> ball's in your court .e your chance.

It's a kind of a run.

> 'on the ball' originated in the sporting arena, and alludes to runners being on the balls of their feet,

It's a kind of a dance.

> ball-dance

It's a kind of escape.

> 'Behind the eight ball' i.e A difficult position from which it is unlikely one can escape.

It's the start of a game.

> play ball is said to start a baseball game or "a whole new ball game" which means a new start.

Yet from middle to end, it stays somehow the same.

> PRobably about the ball that is the same from middle to end.